# Java: How to resolve an octal character, say, '\44', passed on command line?

Tags: java

At compile time this line:

```
System.out.println(new String("\44"));
```

will print ACSII char `"$"`

But, how to print it when `"\44"` is passed as command-line argument?

Comment: How are you passing "\44" in as a command line argument?  I'm on windows and this seems to get ignored when I try to pass it in (ie: arg is missing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically strip the leading `\` and use [`Integer.parseInt(arg, 8)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) since octal is base 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String arg = "\\44"; // simulate command line
    String argOctal = arg.substring(1); // get rid of leading \ to get an octal integer
    int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(argOctal, 8);
    System.out.println('\44');
    System.out.println((char)codePoint);
}
```

prints

```
$
$
```

This assumes you ran like

```
java YourClass "\44"
```